# SQL Database not working after OS upgrade

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, windows-server

Let me begin by saying I’m a noob with anything SQL.

So I was tasked to upgrade the OS on a VM running Server 2012 R2 with SQL Server 2014 Services running on it. Mainly, there is an internal website that runs from that VM. I made a backup just in case but what I did was upgrade it for Server 2016 but when I did that, the website went out but if I restore the backup, the website comes back up. I compared the services running in Configuration manager and the TCP/IP settings and everything is good. I updated SQL Server 2014 to SP3 so it is compatible with Server 2019, it was RTM before no SP. I’m not sure what else to do. I thought it was the SSRS but on the working server, it’s not even on or running. Not sure what else to try. Right now I restored the backup so everything is working as normal. Doing a clean install and re-building is my very last choice right now.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It sounds like everything is working now. Is there a problem you're still trying to solve?

Comment: Hey no it’s still not working. 
So the issue here is that the website that is hosted and linked to the SQL DB is not connecting. When I restore the backup with Server 2012 R2 the website works as normal but when I load up the Server 2016 OS the website does not work even after upgraded the SQL Server to SP3.